# Jenkins variable scope change

Tags: jenkins, devops

Can someone tell me how I can change the scope of a variable in Jenkins Job.Currently I am executing a bash script on a remote system over ssh.The bash script generates a password which I need to pass to email notification configs in a jenkins job.When the variable is passed to email notification config,its empty.
Welcome suggestions to fix it.

Comment: Are you using free-style, pipeline script or scripted pipeline?

Comment: @JRichardsz its a freestyle Job

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a scripted pipeline job like so:

```
node('label') {
  // You would need to make sure only thing printed to stdout is the password
  def password = sh(script: 'ssh ...', returnStdout:true).trim()

  // You can set it in the global environment like this:
  env.Password = password

  // Or use it directly
}
```

Another option is to write the password to a file in the workspace on your agent, then use `readFile()` to read the password from the file.  Here is the syntax for the [basic pipeline steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/).